# A simple function equation

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

I come from a programming background and I can’t find a simple math function. The request might seem strange, but I needed it a graphical context to alter some points locations:

I need a function $f(x) = y$ defined for $x \ge 0$ such that:

- $f(x) \in [0, x)$
- $f(0) = 0$
- $f(x) \approx x$ as $x\to \infty$.
- It has to slowly grow at first — sort of like $x^2$ — and then get closer and closer to x.

The simplest equation form that satisfies this restrictions will do.

I tried to plot this so that I can make myself better understood:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427eo8stqhpe1s

[image]

Actual values don’t matter, just the shape of the plot.

None of the basic functions (and combinations of them) that I tried were doing this (e.g. $x^2, \log x, \sqrt x, 1/x$).

Comment: Thank you and sorry if the question is in any way inappropriate for this site (I use mostly Stack Overflow). Please let me know if I can edit this question to make it more adequate for this site.

Comment: Am I right in saying that you want $y = x$ to be an asymptote? Or is it just that you want the slope of the curve to approach $45^\circ$ (so $y = x - c$ is an asymptote for some suitable constant $c$)?

Comment: @M.Vinay either will do, I will have to test them in my program to see the final results. I think that $y=x$ an asymptote would be better.

Comment: If $y = x$ is an asymptote, then the curve will initially lie below the asymptote and approach it from the right. If $y = x - c$ is an asymptote for an appropriate $c$, then the curve will always be to the left of the asymptote and approach it from the left.

Comment: @M.Vinay yes, I understand. I still need to see the visual result, but I think if y=x an asimptote is better for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This one fulfills your requirements:
$$f(x)=\frac{x^2+x^3}{1+x+x^2}.$$
We have:
$$\forall x>0,\ 0<f(x)<x$$
$$f(0)=0,$$
$$f(x)-x^2=-\frac{x^4}{1+x+x^2}$$
so that $f(x)$ and $x^2$ are very close for small values of $x$, and
$$f(x)-x=-\frac{x}{1+x+x^2}$$
so that $f(x)$ and $x$ get closer and closer as $x\to+\infty$.

It's also cheap to compute with 2 additions, 2 multiplications and 1 division if you proceed thus:

- Compute $x^2$ (1 mult) and $x+x^2$ (1 addition); set $a=x+x^2$.
- Compute $x\times a$ (1 mult); set $b=x\times a$.
- Compute $1+a$ (1 addition); set $c=1+a$.
- Compute $b/c$ (1 division): that's $f(x)$.

Comment: the plot looks good. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

You could use a common hyperbola $y = \sqrt{a^2 + x^2} - a$.

Example with $a = 10$:
[image]

Comment: yes, I saw it. No problem.

Comment: thank you. You guys are great. For now I went with @gniourf_gniourf answer because at first glance it looks faster to compute.

Comment: @bolov Here $y = x - a$ is the asymptote. My misgiving with $y = x$ being the asymptote is that there would be an (ugly) inflection point in that case, as mentioned by Yves.

Comment: the inflection point unless it would be very "abrupt" (I don’t know the right terminology) isn’t a problem.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf That's what I've already said in my comment.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Thought as much. That's perhaps one reason (apart from ease of computation) that your answer is the accepted one. As I said, I find the inflection point ugly, and bolov's last reply-comment (on the question) says he's not fully sure he wants $y = x$ to be the asymptote, and would like to see the graph and then decide. Hence my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a weighting function $w(x)$ that allows you to create a mixture between the functions $x^2$ and $x$, as $\frac{x^2+w(x)x}{1+w(x)}$. Ensure $w(0)=0$ so that the initial behavior is $x^2$  and $w$ growing sufficiently fast that the term $x$ supersedes it.
$$w(x)=x^3\to y=\frac{x^2+x^4}{1+x^3}.$$
$$w(x)=e^x-1\to y=\frac{x^2+x(e^x-1)}{e^x}.$$

[image]

Note that if you really want to reach $y=x$ (and not $y=x-c$), there *must* be an inflection point.

Comment: Nice. I thought of a similar one with a weight function $\theta = 1/e^x$ (and $y = \theta x + (1 - \theta)x$):
$$y = \dfrac{x^2}{e^x} + x\left(1 - \dfrac{1}{e^x}\right)$$

Comment: thank you. You guys are great. For now I went with @gniourf_gniourf answer because at first glance it looks faster to compute.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the derivative of your function.
It has to be positive,increasing and $f'(x→inf)=1$
$f'(x)=tanh(x)$ fits.

$ \int \tanh(x) dx = \log (\cosh (x))+c$

Since we want $f(0)=0$

$\log (\cosh 0)+c=0\Leftrightarrow  c=0$

Therefor $f(x)= \log (\cosh (x)) $ works.

Comment: thank you. You guys are great. For now I went with @gniourf_gniourf answer because at first glance it looks faster to compute.

Answer (score 0):

Using your data, I found that $y=a x^b$ fits very well. My results are $a=0.008755$ and $b=3.134091$. The corresponding $R^2=0.999$.

This is a very flexible form.

Comment: f(x) > x for a certain C, f(x) > x for x > C

Answer (score 0):

A simple function satisfying all above mentioned restrictions is:

$$f(x) = x \left( 1- \frac{1}{1+x} \right)$$

**How to construct such a function?**

1. $f(x)$ should behave like $x$ for $x \rightarrow \infty$ and for $x \gt 0$ it should map into the interval $[0,x)$ which mean $0 \leq f(x) \lt x$. So let's set up the function as
   $$f(x) = x \left( 1- g(x) \right)$$
   To satisfy the above mentioned restriction we conclude:
   $$g(x) \rightarrow 0 \mbox{ for } x \rightarrow \infty \mbox{ and } g(0) = 1 \mbox{ and } 0 \lt g(x) \lt 1 \mbox{ for } x \gt 0$$
2. A simple function that satisfies all this is
   $$g(x) = \frac{1}{1+x}$$
3. Near $0$ the function $f(x)$ behaves like $x^2$ because for $|x| \lt 1$ we have $\frac{1}{1+x} = 1 - x + x^2 - x^3 +- \cdots$ (geometric series). So
   $$f(x) = x\left( 1 - ( 1 - x + x^2 - x^3 +- \cdots) \right) = x^2 - x^3 +- \cdots \approx x^2 \mbox{ for } x \mbox{ close to }0$$